# DyGraph dependancy

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

I was trying to use Dygraph for chart representation and I found the code in `https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs`, but it has so many dependancy files, I found it irritating. Is there a single file which will accomodate all the required js files for its proper working??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to include the file:

https://github.com/downloads/danvk/dygraphs/dygraph-combined.js

for using dygraphs. Download it to your webroot and include it from there. Do not include it directly from the github URL. There are no other dependencies. (I've been using this for a few months now)

Comment: is it possible to get the from date and to date when a particular time range is selected using a graph?

Comment: @DaSilva Try using this reference: http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html I think what you are looking for is contained there with methods like yAxisRanges